# Kedro Pipeline contains no nodes after applying all provided filters

Tags: python-3.x, nodes, pipeline, kedro, vscode-python

ValueError: Pipeline contains no nodes after applying all provided filters

```
src/pipelines/data_processing<br>
src/pipelines/data_science<br>
src/pipelines/data_project<br>
src/pipelines/pipeline2<br>

Kedro build-docs-> dont'work
pip install pip-tools
pip install -r src/requirements.txt
pip install "kedro-datasets[<group>]"


Nothing works
[kedro v0.18.7]
[Python 3.10.8]
```

My project was working perfectly and at some point I tried to implement Modular Pipelines and then I ran the command to create a new pipeline.
[kedro pipeline create pipeline2]
The idea was to create a parallel pipeline to run with the main pipeline. [data-processing]
Before running the project I realized that it was not necessary and ran the command to delete pipeline2
[kedro pipeline delete pipeline2]
Since then my project stopped working
I tried to create another pipeline with the name of my main pipeline, but without success.
I tried to create another empty pipeline and pass my codes to [nodes.py] and [pipelines.py], also without success
I tried running [kedro build-docs] to refactor, also to no avail.
I do not know what else to do.
[kedro run] returns [Pipeline contains no nodes after applying all provided filters]

When I run the command [kedro registry list] it returns [**default**]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @eduardo_eng_datos, I'm sorry you're having a rough experience. Looks like you are trying several commands for different things and they are all failing. Could you use backticks (`) to identify machine outputs better, and paste full tracebacks so we can help you identify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after implementing my own pipeline. Digging into the error message:

```
function in the 'src.pipelines.your_new_pipeline' module does not expose a 'create_pipeline' function, so no pipelines defined therein will be returned by 'find_pipelines'.
```

To fix this, add the following at `src/pipelines/your_new_pipeline/__init__.py`:

```py
"""Expose the create_pipeline func!"""

from .pipeline import create_pipeline
```

This allows `kedro` to effectively run `from your_new_pipeline import create_pipeline`.

Answer (score -1):

The main folders of existing pipelines in the project were backed up.[data_processing],[data_science] and [data_project]

The command was executed to recreate the pipelines again [kedro pipeline create ]

Folder structure was recreated and nodes.py and pipelines.py of backup files were replaced

After a new command [kedro run] the problem was solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).